# How to set a timeout to the database connection in SORM?

Tags: database, connection, timeout, sorm

I use H2 database in embedded mode with SORM.
If the database is busy then SORM just continue to wait. There are no exception, nothing happens. This is misleading. :(
So how i can set the db connection timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How come it's misleading and how come exceptions are better? If you need the process to be non-blocking just use [Future](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Future) like so:

```
future{ Db.query[Artist].fetch() }.foreach{ artists => ... }
```

Consider this to be a non-blocking version of the following:

```
val artists = Db.query[Artist].fetch()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to know that the connection is wrong, I'd rather the exception or something else.

Comment: @Tolsi See [`alarm` and `awaitEither`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Futures$)